# How to accelerate/avoid multiplication for large matrices in Matlab?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, sparse-matrices

The setting is here.

X:  6000x8000 non-sparse matrix

B:  8000x1 sparse vector with only tens of non-zeros

d:  positive number

M:  is sparsified X'X, i.e. thresholding the elements smaller than d in magnitude to be 0.
Only hundreds of elements are left.  So (X' * X - M) have many small elements and is not sparse.

I want to compute the vector  y=(X' * X - M)* B and can rewrite as y=X' * (X * B) - M*B. 
The first part is fast enough, but the second part involves X'*X, and is very very slow.

Could any one help me to accelerate this computation?

Thanks a million!

Comment:  I don't think MO is the right place for this question, maybe Stack Overflow http://stackoverflow.com/ is better.

Comment: I agree that this is completely inappropriate, voting to close

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't compute the entries that would be multiplied with the zero entries of $B$. That is, take the submatrix $X_{nz}$ of $X$ consisting of those columns corresponding with the nonzero entries of $B$, and take $B_{nz}$ to be the concatenation of all nonzero entries of $B$. Then compute the sparsification of $X^T \cdot X_{nz}$ and multiply that by $B_{nz}$.

Answer (score -3):

Matlab has a sparse matrix type.